# Google Analytics with MonoTouch crashes on device

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, xamarin.ios

I am trying to use Google Analytics with a MonoTouch application (iPhone). It works great on the simulator but crashes on startup on an actual iPhone.

This is apparently due to a bug in the XCode linker than doesn't allow libraries with Thumb and non-Thumb instruction sets to be linked together.

http://monotouch.net/Documentation/Troubleshoot

From what I can see, MonoTouch is compiled with non Thumb. The Google Analytics lib is compiled with Thumb.

Has anyone figured out a workaround for this?

Clarification - We are using GA to track the page & event views of our own app. We are not writing an app to query the GA API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.1, the Google Analytics SDK provides a nothumb version of the library.

Answer (score 5):

Hello i've done some work with the Analytics API

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2058130/Analytics.zip

here you are the DLLs i used, this are already monotouch precompiled DLL's you need to import to your project the 3 of them in order to use it

here is the documentation of the dll

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataLibraries.html

Hope this helps

Alex

Comment: It appears these are geared towards reading the GA API. Is there any functionality for Page & Event tracking? We are trying to see how users are interacting with our app.

Comment: AFAIK Nope unfortunately there is no functionality for Page & Event tracking, its just the Client API to consume data from GA :/ as Geoff Norton pointed we should ping google on the link provided. Sorry i tough you wanted the Client Data API

Answer (score 4):

There is no workaround at this time, you should "star" this issue to let Google know its important for you:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=1705